# Re-activated virtual environment missing module

Tags: python, virtualenv

Here are my steps:

```
mkdir venv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
foo
# everything works
deactivate
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
foo
#...
ImportError: No module named 'click'
```

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
        author='...',
        author_email='...',
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [
                'foo=foo.cli:main']
            },
        name='foo',
        packages=find_packages(),
        version='0.0.0')
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. It's not the first time I've used virtualenv but I've never had this problem.

Comment: Which version of _setuptools_ are you using?

Comment: At least `install_requires=['Click']` is missing in your `setup.py` script. But I don't know why it works the first time…

Comment: Yeah, you're right. `install_requires=['Click']` fixes it. Thanks! Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it works the first time, just after virtualenv creation (I can't reproduce this bug). But at least `install_requires=['Click']` is missing in your `setup.py`.

To fix that:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo=foo.cli:main']
    },
    name='foo',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.0.0',
    install_requires=['Click']
)
```